# Code for Border on PDF gives Missing \endcsname on Windows but not Mac

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I have the following code to create a boxed outline on my PDF. It runs successfully on a Mac with LaTeXiT but is failing on a Windows Machine no matter what Latex installation I am using. I don't understand what error to tackle here.

The code I am running is as follows:

```
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
```

The error is as follows:

```
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.75 \{
       \% logical pages=1,\% \} \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1} \{ border
```

Comment: you have only shown a fragment of the code you used and only a fragment of the error message. That makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: your code shows `{% logical pages..` the fragment of the error message shows `\{ \% logical pages`  with `\ ` ?

Comment: I believe the ```\``` is escaping the percent sign when I compile this in R Markdown.

Comment: you hadn't even mentioned markdown!!!!!! If R markdown is generating invalid tex then you will get a tex error but that then is an R issue not a tex one.  But you have not shown a usable example nor shown the error that you got so really it is impossible to help unless you edit the question.

Comment: Do you see any obvious errors or missing code in this section?
```  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
```

Comment: the tex error fragment (you did not show the actual error message)  confirms that the code you show is not the code that was passed to tex.